# How to add a custom view on an image view dynamically/programatically in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view, android-framelayout

I have to make an app in which an image is loaded from the gallery and a rectangle can be drawn on the image to focus a specific part of the image. The rectangle is drawn dynamically and it can be re-sized and dragged. So i have made a custom view for my rectangle. Now i want to add this rectangle view on my image view. How is this adding of a custom view on a image view possible dynamically. I tried using frame layout but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView is now ViewGroup so no View can be added to the ImageView. Instead you can draw directly on the ImageView itself by overriding the method `onDraw(Canvas)` of the ImageView.

An other possibility is to have your view with the rectangle over the image view and have a transparent background. To have two view over one another you can use the `RelativeLayout` Object.

Comment: The rectangle has to be drawn only if the user wants it( i.e. there is a button above the image view(Draw Rectangle), if the user clicks the button a rectangle with default dimensions and position is drawn, which the user can then change by dragging n all). So how to call the onDraw when the button is clicked?